My project in Flutter does not work on Macbok
enter image description here
All programs and libraries are up to date.
I made the updates and introductions requested from me. But it didn't help.
Jdk is installed. The path has been introduced.Plugins downloads have been made.It runs smoothly on a Windows computer. It opens smoothly without any warning.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.

Looks like some issue with the generated Info.plist. You can delete the ios project and recreate it with flutter create . --platforms=ios
